# Repeated Name/Password Requests Using MS Access 2003 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

We recently moved a database from MS SQL Server 2000 to MS SQL Server 2008. Everything works as expected with our main .NET client application but we are having problems with a MS Access 2003 application which connects via ODBC. A System DSN is used to make the connection.

When the database was running on SQL Server 2000 the Access application would request a user name and password once when the program was first started. Now, with the database running on SQL Server 2008 a user name and password dialog is requested every time a different table is accessed I believe.

This behavior occurs when using either the user account we have used for years and it also occurs if I use the database system admin account ( I know this is bad practice, it was just a test. )

What do I need to reconfigure to return to the previous, desirable behavior where the user is only authenticated a single time?

Comment: So you're connecting through a `*.dsn` file, as opposed to an ODBC connection on the computer itself?

Comment: No, we are using the ODBC System DSN connection that is on the computer which has the MS Access program.

Comment: Are you connecting to the tables directly or through queries?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using a "DSN-Less" connection to MS SQL, microsoft provide instructions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892490

The relevant connection string can be found here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#p3

All this aside, JMK's question is important, the method above is for if you are having linked tables to the server present in your Access database, however when working with dedicated database server's I always advise using "ADO" connections rather than "DAO" as this will avail better performance (especially if you are running queries)

If it is just queries you need to run then consider either the ADO method or take a look at the "Pass through" queries option, this like ADO will have the server doing the work rather than the local machine and the performance will be greatly improved.